# Is PHP's password_hash FIPS compliant?

Tags: php, password-protection, fips, php-password-hash

I believe `hash('sha256', $pw)` is FIPS compliant, but I know for certain that an attack vector is possible with using that function. Also, there is no salt (so I would have to encounter that implementation and I would rather not).  Is `password_hash`/`password_verify` FIPS compliant?

Comment: password_hash has a salt 'built in'. if its just a matter of the particular hash algorithm it uses, you can decide that.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98214/why-should-i-choose-sha-such-as-sha-512-instead-of-bcrypt-or-pbkdf2-for-fips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

1. [FIPS 140-2 does not certify password hashing algorithms.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/98221/82155) As such, `password_hash` cannot be FIPS compliant, because FIPS simply doesn't apply to it.
2. To the best of my knowledge, the hash implementations used by `hash()` (which are part of the PHP core) have not been FIPS certified. If you specifically need a FIPS-compliant implementation, and you have a FIPS-compliant OpenSSL library installed, you may be able to use `openssl_digest()` as an alternative. (However, remember that this is not a secure method of storing passwords, even with a salt!)